# Meaning of a linq statement

Tags: c#

I saw this code and trying to understand the ling. feater.groupId = 30

```
    var myData = await _source.GetDataByIdNumber(staffId);

    if(!myData.select(x=>x.Id).contains(feater.groupId))
    {
      status.IsValid = false;
    }
```

How do I interprete this line in sql or english?

```
    if(!myData.select(x=>x.Id).contains(feater.groupId))
```

Comment: I suspect that's not the actual code - I'd expect `Select` and `Contains` instead of `select` and `contains`.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to dissect your code and observe its behavior.  When you debug, isolate the result of `myData.Select(x => x.Id)` (likely by storing the result in its own variable).  What is that result?  What is the value of `feater.groupId`?  What do you semantically suspect `.Contains()` means when used on that result with a given value?

Comment: I choose English:) - If there is no record in myData with Id = feater.groupId

Comment: I updated the code. Ok. I will check what you suggested

Comment: Your updated code is still not your actual code, I suspect.

Comment: That is the actual code. I brought out the  section I will like to interpret

Comment: ! Means **NOT** 
So with `var a = 5` you can check if var a is something other than 5. 
`if (a != 4) { Console.WriteLine("A is not 4"); }` This means if `var a` is **not** `5`

Comment: @user2320476: In that case your code has *custom* methods called `select` and `contains` (which don't adhere to standard C# naming conventions).  We don't know what your custom methods do.  They are, by definition, custom.  C# is case-sensitive, `select` is not `Select` and `contains` is not `Contains`.  You'll have to examine your methods to see what they do.

Comment: That is equivalent of `if(!myData.Any(q => q.Id == feater.groupId))`, basically it checks if `myData` has no items with `Id` equals to `feater.groupId`

Comment: @user2320476 edited answer to include SQL query equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

"If" check is satisfied if none of the myData entities have an Id value of 30

Assuming standard C# Linq operators as per comments!

```
 if(!myData.Select(x=>x.Id).Contains(feater.groupEntityId));
```

Selects the Id property of all entities. Determines if value 30 is contained within the selected sequence.

Direct T-SQL translation is:

```
 SELECT CASE
    WHEN 30 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM <YourTable>
    )
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END
```

So, if the supplied value is equal to any of the Ids returned by the select sub-query, return true, else return false.